# I have a problem with my foreign key in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting this error in my laravel migration:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `krada`.`#sql-2d10_cc` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed"      ) (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint
>   `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references
>   `categories` (`id`) on dele      te cascade)
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `krada`.`#sql-2d10_cc` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed"      )

Comment: your SQL for adding foreign key looks right to me. To isolate the issue simply run the alter statement to see if it still throws error (in case you have values in posts table that have category_id as null or doesn't match any id in categories table).
How is table creation 'krada' is related to this. Some more information about the setup would help.

Comment: It could help if you show us your migrations.